# How to place something after an object of a different size correctly?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management, casting

If there is a pool of memory containing a struct like this:

```
struct Header {
    /* fields */
    size_t arr_size;
    some_t arr[];
}

struct Header x = {...};
/* filling x.arr */
```

Is it safe to use `(Header*)(x.arr + x.arr_size)` as a location to put the next struct in? Will not it violate the strict aliasing rule if there is no other pointer to that location?

If it is not safe, what is the correct way to place a struct (or anything else) after `x.arr`?

#### UPD:

Seems like the question needs some clarification:

A pool of memory means I have allocated enough space around to play with.

The example might be unclear / redundant, so consider this one:

```
void *mem; // an initialized pointer to lots of memory
some_t *item_a = (some_t *) mem; // item_a has a known size with no caveats
/* initializing item_a here */
other_t *item_b = (other_t *) item_a + 1;
```

Is it valid to store something at `item_b`?

Comment: No, you can't know where that would possibly be pointing to from Header's scope

Comment: You need to consider padding as well.

Comment: I don't get the question clearly.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why is it that you care? This looks like [The XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: If the array size will be dynamic, then it should be `some_t *arr;`, and then `Header` simply contains a `size_t` and a pointer. You can't define a `struct` with a dynamic contiguous length. The size of `arr` has no bearing on the size of `Header`, since they are entirely separate blocks of memory.

Comment: You shouldn’t be trying to initialize a structure with a FAM (flexible array member).  Strictly, you’re not able to allocate space for the array. You should only use dynamic allocation.  That said, GCC does allow it in some places.  But you can’t create arrays of such structures because arrays have to be spaced uniformly at intervals of the size of the object, and the size doesn’t include the FAM.  You need to rethink your concerns.

Comment: I know what FAM is. Also, everything is happening inside a manually managed memory pool, so there is no need to worry about its initialization and / or memory allocation. I updated the question with a new example, it might be clearer

Comment: @EricPostpischil I see your point. I did not mean to say "can't", and I should have edited that particular word. As for the purpose, it's much easier to avoid memory alignment issues if you don't allocate `arr` as a FAM, especially when the context deals with consecutive instances of `Header` in a memory pool. I see my concerns are also stated in user7231's answer, and that was exactly my point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do what you want with some care. Cast itself doesn't violate anything. The problem is your second header may be misaligned. `Header`'s address alignment should correspond to largest alignment of its members, in your case it's either alignof(size_t) or alignof(some_t). For example if `size_t` is `uint32_t` and `some_t` is `int16_t`, then you may have to add padding `(Header *) (x.arr + x.arr_size + (x.arr_size % 2 ? 2 : 0))` so that address of `Header` is multiple of 4. So use something like this (gcc):

```
inline
struct Header *
next_header(struct Header *h)
{
    size_t sz = sizeof(*h) + sizeof(some_t) * h->arr_size;
    size_t a = __alignof__(*h);
    return (Header *) ((char *) h + (sz % a ? a - sz % a : 0));
}
```

Note that alignment is not enforced on some architectures (e.g. x86), misaligned access just incurs performance hit. On others it's a crash or worse.

Answer (score -1):

In order to insure relative placement of different objects (in the general, not OOP meaning of the term), you'd have to allocate the space they share as a piece; the memory management system doesn't care what you do with the space you have allocated, but makes no provisions for how individuals allocations are placed relative to one another.